# Django file sharing between users

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am creating file sharing app. i have multiple user. 
plz find below my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from Box.models import user_files


class Loginform(forms.Form):
    username=forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class UserRegistration(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password',widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat Password',widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields= ('username','first_name','email')

    def clean_password2(self):
        cd=self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password']!=cd['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords do not match')
        return cd['password2']

class Fileupload(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= user_files
        fields = ('Filename','Browse')
```

and my model.py

```
from django.db import models

class user_files(models.Model):
    Filename = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Browse = models.FileField()
```

i have used django in built user model to store user data and model user_files for storing files. So now how can i distinguish which file is uploaded by which user? and how can i share among other user? i am stuck at this point.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put up a field uploaded_by which is foreign key to User model, this will help you identify which user uploaded it, and for download you'll just have to put up a link of the file in html.

Comment: if i put field uploaded_by , then i need to update it manually, right?  if yes...  how to do it?

Comment: you must be accepting files via a form right so when that form is sent there you can do something like "form_object.uploaded_by = request.user" so you won't have to do it manually.

Comment: for displaying link for uploaded file, how to get that link?